# Parsing thrown custom exceptions from PostgreSQL to EJB?

Tags: java, postgresql, persistence, ejb-3.0

We wish to have a system where PostgreSQL throws a custom exceptions detailing the error condition when performing a transaction, for example insufficient funds, item already sold etc.

The interim solution is for retrieving the `com.postgresql.util.PSQLException` that is wrapped in a `PersistenceException`. However this forces the package to have a build and test dependency on the PostgreSQL library, losing some modularity.

Is there some way we can return and parse an exception from PostgreSQL in a more elegant or more standard way?

Comment: How do you analyse PSQLException? Do you parse exception message only or do you need access to some special attributes of the exception?

Comment: This was correct, I needed `getSQLState` which was actually part of the parent class `SQLException`. I just cast it to SQLException instead and it worked appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the PostgreSQL-specific exceptions in your own exception class.  Pass the PSQLException as the cause when you create your own exception class so that it shows up in the full stack trace and `Exception.getCause()` calls.   Then the package will only a have a run-time dependence on PostGreSQL.